# Assembler in C using functions

Tags: c, function, using, assembly

HI all, 
I am trying to design an assembler in C based on some instruction sets.
I want to read a assembly language file containing instructions. IN the hex file there is hex data, integer data and negative integer data. I need to convert that data into 8 bit hexadecimal data , out of which 6 bit represents hexadecimal data and the remaining 2 bit will be of opcode.
For example ;
ldc 0x1000 
output: 00100000 (opcode of ldc is 00)
ldc -3;
output : fffffd00 (6 bit 2s complement of +3).

I am trying ltoa to convert the integer into hexadecimal, but its giving string as output so i am not able to append 0s .
PLease suggest urgentl

Comment: Why can you not append 0s to a string? Also, I suggest looking at the sscanf() and sprintf() functions (or variants) instead, they are probably going to be your best friends in a project like this

Answer (score 2):

You seem to confuse bits with nibbles.  One hexadecimal digit represents 4 bits.  The opcode can store a 24 bit constant, 6 nibbles.  Read the value from the string with strtol() and left-shift it by 8.  Or with the opcode.

Comment: Thanks but i need to read data and convert into 8 bit hexadecimal data out of which 6 bit will represent the actual data and two LSBs will represent opcode.

Comment: You need to think about how you are going to store 0x1000 (4096) into 6 bits (2^6 = 64).  At least 13 bits are required.  No machine exists that has 2 bits for an opcode, that allows for only 4 instructions.  I can only assume you are confusing bits and bytes.  One byte requires two hexadecimal digits.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble